# Voltage regulator 5v 1.5A

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-source

I have voltage source of 7v 250mA. Question is, when I apply it to regulator do I get 5v and 1.5A on the output of regulator?Or do I need 1.5A for a linear regulator ?   How much current would I need to get 1.5A out when using a buck regulator?

Comment: What regulator are you using? if you are using a linear regulator, (like a 7805) the maximum output current will be the same as the input current i.e. 250mA, if you are using a DC-DC converter the output current will depend on the efficiency of the converter.

Comment: @autistic - that change doesn't make sense and puts previous answers in jeopardy. Be very careful about making changes like this. Also, what does "Or do I need 1.5A for a linear regulator ?" actually mean - it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Andy  I didnt see the answers .Perhaps early onset dementia .I could not believe that someone with a reasonable reputation would believe that regulators were more than 100% efficient .I thought that editing the question would be kinder than letting it get pelted with downvotes which are very easy to get here compared to other sites .

Comment: @Autistic well it doesn't look like it received any down votes prior to the change and the additions you made still don't make sense.

Answer (score 9):

Power out can never be greater than power in. You are expecting an output of 5 V at 1.5 A i.e. 7.5 watts. Power in is 7 V x 0.25 A = 1.75 watts.

Conclusion is you can't get what you want from what you are supplying.

Comment: How much current I can get?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic What regulator are you considering?

Comment: Could you do for this regulartor: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2940c.pdf              it is just 1A instead of 1.5A

Comment: @VladimirDjukic that regulator will "steal" 10mA down the GND pin and therefore the maximum current you can output is input current  minus 10 mA = 240 mA.

Comment: I will need to check this when I come home, thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka: Well said Andy, and that too is the ideal case, without considering efficiency. In real case, situation would be completely different.

Answer (score 3):

Considering Vin=7V and Iin=250 mA and if you are using switching regulator, in that case  Pin = 1.75 W ( ~ Vin* Iin), So for Vo=5V and considering 100 % efficiency ( which is not possible practically ), you can get 0.35A at output.

Note :

**n ( efficiency )= Po/Pin**

If 95% efficiency, Po=1.66W and Io=0.33A.

So depending upon efficiency of your regulator, you will get output current capability of your regulator.

Comment: You won't get more current at the output than the current at the input for *any* linear voltage regulators.

Comment: @Icy True, but linear regulators were not specified by OP or referred to by Electroholic

Comment: Could you show me calculations, how you get 0.33A?

Comment: He has: Pin = Vin * Iin;  Pout = Pin * efficiency; IOut = POut / VOut.

Comment: I will need to check this when I come home, thanks!